# MS Word: How do I get wrap a word with rounded rectangle like this in this Web?

Tags: ms-word, formatting

In MS Word, how do I wrap a particular word around with a rounded rectangle like shown below. Example shown below is using CSS styling in Web.

[image]

Comment: If you want rounded corners then the only way is to insert a *Rounded Rectangle* shape, add the text to the shape and set the position of the shape to be *inline with text*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Rectangle then go to "Format Tab" Click "Wrap Text" & choose "Square[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utFvd.png)